# Is there a term for "can be missing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is for an item in a collection (like a bag), that may or may not be present. Basically, it's presence is not guaranteed, but it is valid to go search for it.

The exact situation I'm in is I'm designing a RESTful API and trying to describe a property for a route that could return a 404. It's not so much that it's optional, it's just that the item with this ID hasn't been created yet.

I'm using [RAML](http://raml.org/) to design this and want a good name for my trait.

**The qualifier for a good name for my trait is:** that it fits well with this sentence structure: "projects are X", where X is the trait name. So: "pluralNoun are adjective".

This is the qualifier because the trait is referenced in the markup like: `is: [X]`. So, I want something that flows well with `is` or `are`.

Is there a term for this? Right now, the only thing I've got is "missingable", which is obviously made up and... non-ideal. I'm not wild about `optional`, because the item isn't **really** optional, it just doesn't exist yet. I searched and searched online and couldn't find anything that fit my bill, so I came here!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I ended up using `potentially_absent` as my RAML trait name, but I think I'll use `unaccounted` in the next revision!

Comment: Why not say *...could possibly be missing*?

Comment: I was really looking for a single adjective when I opened the question. Since then I've realized that's not required at all, and I ended up using `potentially absent`, so that's basically the same thing. The end use of this word is to describe a trait for something in CS, so a single word was desirable, but not required. Anyway, TL;DR; I basically did that after other people talked me to my senses =D.

Comment: Well, the item's presence is indeterminate. Don

Comment: Description updated to hopefully move this off "On Hold". to make me happier =). Let me know if editing the answer or providing more detail would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a potential property? I would usually use that for a term that may or may not be present. (Posting as an answer at your request.)

Comment: Just to wrap it all up, I ended up using `potentially_absent` after John got the idea in my brain. Thanks again! Couldn't come up with that word to save my life!

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, we always call such things `optional`.

Comment: Hmmmmm... That's not bad, I didn't think of it like that. But, since you're CS, I can go a bit more in depth. I'm designing an API and trying to describe a property for a route that could return a 404. It's not so much that it's optional, it's just that the item with this ID hasn't been created yet. Think optional fits that? Or got something better?

Comment: How about a **potential** property?

Comment: Oooo, I like that more than `optional` @JohnClifford, thanks. I think I'll use that for now, but it's sort of like the inverse of what I want. Whereas `potential` means: "having or showing the capacity to become or develop into something in the future." I'm looking for: "having or showing the ability to be absent." It's splitting hairs, so I'm going with that for now, but I still feel that there should be a term for what I want. Thanks!

Comment: After John got my brain seeded with `potential`, I ended up using `potentially_absent` for the property. Thanks! I think that's perfect! If you wanna make an answer for me to accept, I'll happily do that @JohnClifford.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with ***unaccounted for***, and if you must go with a single word, ***unaccounted.*** The meaning is precisely what you are asking for: possibly missing, and certainly valid to be searched for.

Comment: Oh wow! I really like this one! I sort of settled on `potentially_absent` for this round of my documentation, but I think I'll either refactor to use `unaccounted` or do that in a future revision. Thanks so much for your input! Leaving the original answer as accepted (because I said I would), but I upvoted ya!

Comment: Thanks buddy! Yeah, I was a little disappointed that you picked the original answer, because I really liked mine. But I really appreciate you taking the time to pass along the comment. I really wanted to help, but at least you liked the word/phrase! :-)

Comment: Hey man, you commented on my question! The least I can do is reply! I appreciate any input given, for sure =).